# Drake Visualizer : Unknown file extension in readPolyData when using .dae file

Tags: drake

I am trying to add a custom mesh (a torus) `.dae` file for collision and visual to my `.sdf` model.

When I run my program, drake visualizer gives the following error

```
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/lcmUtils.py", line 119, in handleMessage
    callback(msg)
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/drakevisualizer.py", line 352, in onViewerLoadRobot
    self.addLinksFromLCM(msg)
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/drakevisualizer.py", line 376, in addLinksFromLCM
    self.addLink(Link(link), link.robot_num, link.name)
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/drakevisualizer.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.geometry.extend(Geometry.createGeometry(link.name + ' geometry data', g))
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/drakevisualizer.py", line 272, in createGeometry
    polyDataList, visInfo = Geometry.createPolyDataFromFiles(geom)
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/drakevisualizer.py", line 231, in createPolyDataFromFiles
    polyDataList = [ioUtils.readPolyData(filename)]
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/ioUtils.py", line 25, in readPolyData
    raise Exception('Unknown file extension in readPolyData: %s' % filename)
Exception: Unknown file extension in readPolyData: /my_path/model.dae
```

Since `prius.sdf` also uses `prius.dae`, I assume this is possible.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr `drake_visualizer` doesn't load dae files. If you put a similarly named `.obj` file in the same folder it will load that (and you can leave your sdf file still referencing the dae file).

Long answer:

`drake_visualizer` has a very specific, arbitrary protocol for loading files. Given an arbitrary file name (e.g., `my_geometry.dae`) it will

1. Strip off the extension.
2. Try the following files (in order), loading the first one it finds:

   - `my_geometry.vtm`
   - `my_geometry.vtp`
   - `my_geometry.obj`
   - original extension.

It can load: `vtm`, `vtp`, `ply`, `obj`, and `stl` files.

The worst thing is if you have both a vtp and an obj file in the same folder with the same name and you *specify* the obj, it'll still favor the vtp file.